# Change Apple ID with previously used email

Tags: email, apple-id

I previously had 2 apple IDs using (1) Gmail and (2) my university email.

The deletion of (1) was completed, requested on Dec 9, 2019, and completed on Dec 25, 2019.

Now I would like to change the email of (2) into the email I previously used for (1). However, the website said that "This email address is not available. Choose a different address."

May I ask what's the issue of this?

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to contact Apple directly to address this.

Comment: Deleting an email address from iCloud doesn't remove it from Apple's database.  You're getting that message because it was previously used.  Only Apple can fix this.